# Get component using route param in routes.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, quasar-framework

I want the router to show a component based on the parameter in the path.

So currently my routes look like this:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/pages/1",
    component: () => import("pages/page-1.vue")
  }
]
```

and I want them to look something like this:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/pages/:page",
    component: () => import("pages/page-{whatgoeshere?}.vue")
  }
]
```

Comment: Why would you need to do this? You're not going to be creating pages at runtime so you can just manually enter each page number. `"pages/1" => "page-1.vue"` etc.

Comment: I have a lot (200ish) page which are migrated from flat html pages and I need to show in my app. Each one has a component which is mostly html. I know this is not an ideal situation, but it's the best solution we have to work with some legacy content.

Comment: Having a dynamic path of `/pages/123` or `/pages/456` is totally independent of having the file as a single Vue file **per entry**. You don't even need to do that, use a single component and inject the content inside of it. You cannot, should not (and it's not even possible to manage) 3000 `.vue` components.

Comment: @FelixEklöf the solution you deleted is totally viable and fine. I recommend that you undelete it.

Comment: Sure, it works, but I deleted it because I guess it doesn't really solve the problem since I realized you'd have to import the 200 pages components instead. Then you might as well just specify the routes which is a better solution in my opinion.

Comment: If there is no way to use the path param to dynamically create the component name then I think @FelixEklöf's answer is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could create just one page component `DynamicPage.vue` and then render the desired component there.

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/pages/:page",
    component: () => import("pages/DynamicPage.vue")
  }
]
```

**DynamicPage.vue**

```js
<template>
  <component :is="`page-${$route.params.page}`" />
</template>

<script>
// Import all page components
</script>
```